# EclipseLink MOXy JSON Serialization

Tags: java, json, eclipselink, marshalling, moxy

I have got a sample class:

```
class Zoo {
    public Collection<? extends Animal> animals;
}
```

When serialized with MOXy, I am getting:

```
{
    "bird": [
        {
            "name": "bird-1",
            "wingSpan": "6 feets",
            "preferredFood": "food-1"
        }
    ],
    "cat": [
        {
            "name": "cat-1",
            "favoriteToy": "toy-1"
        }
    ],
    "dog": [
        {
            "name": "dog-1",
            "breed": "bread-1",
            "leashColor": "black"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is it using array indicators "[]", while bird, cat, and dog are not arrays?
Second, is there a way to get rid of "bird", "cat", and "dog"?

In other words, I am trying to get to:

```
{
        {
            "name": "bird-1",
            "wingSpan": "6 feets",
            "preferredFood": "food-1"
        }
    ,
        {
            "name": "cat-1",
            "favoriteToy": "toy-1"
        }
    ,
        {
            "name": "dog-1",
            "breed": "bread-1",
            "leashColor": "black"
        }
}
```

Thanks,
Behzad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**QUESTION #1**

> Why is it using array indicators "[]", while bird, cat, and dog are
>   not arrays?

To get this JSON representation you have mapped your model with the `@XmlElementRef` annotation which tells JAXB to use the value of the `@XmlRootElement` annotation as the inheritance indicator.  With MOXy's JSON binding these become keys.  We make the value of these keys JSON arrays since keys are not allowed to repeat.

**Zoo**

In your model you have the `@XmlElementRef` annotation on your `animals` field/property.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;

class Zoo {
    @XmlElementRef
    public Collection<? extends Animal> animals;
}
```

**Animal**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Bird.class, Cat.class, Dog.class})
public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;

}
```

**Bird**

On each of your subclasses you have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Bird extends Animal {

    private String wingSpan;
    private String preferredFood;

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
   "bird" : [ {
      "name" : "bird-1",
      "wingSpan" : "6 feets",
      "preferredFood" : "food-1"
   } ],
   "cat" : [ {
      "name" : "cat-1",
      "favoriteToy" : "toy-1"
   } ],
   "dog" : [ {
      "name" : "dog-1",
      "breed" : "bread-1",
      "leashColor" : "black"
   } ]
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

---

**QUESTION #2**

> Second, is there a way to get rid of "bird", "cat", and "dog"?

You are going to need some sort of inheritance indicator to represent the various subclasses.

***OPTION #1 - `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue`***

Here I do this using MOXy's `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue` annotations.

**Zoo**

```
import java.util.Collection;

class Zoo {
    public Collection<? extends Animal> animals;
}
```

**Animal**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Bird.class, Cat.class, Dog.class})
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;

}
```

**Bird**

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorValue;

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("bird")
public class Bird extends Animal {

    private String wingSpan;
    private String preferredFood;

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
   "animals" : [ {
      "type" : "bird",
      "name" : "bird-1",
      "wingSpan" : "6 feets",
      "preferredFood" : "food-1"
   }, {
      "type" : "cat",
      "name" : "cat-1",
      "favoriteToy" : "toy-1"
   }, {
      "type" : "dog",
      "name" : "dog-1",
      "breed" : "bread-1",
      "leashColor" : "black"
   } ]
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

***OPTION #2 - `@XmlClassExtractor`***

**ClassExtractor (AnimalExtractor)**

You can write some code that will determine the appropriate subclass based on the JSON content.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassExtractor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.*;

public class AnimalExtractor extends ClassExtractor {

    @Override
    public Class extractClassFromRow(Record record, Session session) {
        if(null != record.get("@wingSpan") || null != record.get("@preferredFood")) {
            return Bird.class;
        } else if(null != record.get("@favoriteToy")) {
            return Cat.class;
        } else {
            return Dog.class;
        }
    }

}
```

**Animal**

The `@XmlClassExtractor` annotation is used to specify the `ClassExtractor`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlClassExtractor;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Bird.class, Cat.class, Dog.class})
@XmlClassExtractor(AnimalExtractor.class)
public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;

}
```

**Bird**

Due to how MOXy processes the `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` annotations, any of the data you want to be made available to the `ClassExtractor` will need to be annotated with `@XmlAttribute`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Bird extends Animal {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String wingSpan;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String preferredFood;

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
   "animals" : [ {
      "wingSpan" : "6 feets",
      "preferredFood" : "food-1",
      "name" : "bird-1"
   }, {
      "favoriteToy" : "toy-1",
      "name" : "cat-1"
   }, {
      "breed" : "bread-1",
      "leashColor" : "black",
      "name" : "dog-1"
   } ]
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-inheritance-eclipselink-moxy.html

---

**DEMO CODE**

The following demo code can be used with both of the mappings described above.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Zoo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum14210676/input.json");
        Zoo zoo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Zoo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(zoo, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply. I am getting an exception during de-serialization. I was not able to update the post. I have added this information as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BehzadPirvali - Could you post the issue you are seeing as a new question?

Comment: OK, Sure I will post it as new question

Comment: I have just posted it as a new question, Thanks

Comment: @BehzadPirvali - I have posted an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14246467/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - Thanks for this clear and good example . But I would like to know how can I access the value in the parent element (say a field in `Zoo` inside `ClassExtractor` ? I have posted this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253383/access-parent-json-element-in-eclipselink-moxy-s-classextractor too. Thanks